# Extract outer class type from inner class instance passed to template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, traits

I have a group of classes and inside each one is defined a nested class always with the same name.

```
class A {
public:
    class Common {};
    ...
};

class B {
public:
    class Common {};
    ...
};
```

I am trying to write a template function like this (NOT compiling code):

```
template<typename T, typename... ARGS>
void foo(T::Common tc, ARGS... args) {
    T t(tc, args...);
    // do stuff
}
```

And I would like to use it as follow:

```
{
    ...
    A::Common ac();
    foo(ac, 42, "Hello");
    ....
}
```

How could I extract the outer class type from the type on the inner class instance passed to the function? Maybe with `<traits>`, but I am very newbie about it...

Comment: Your outer class type is simply `T` in the function `foo`, if I understand things correctly.

Comment: @DanielLangr `T` is in a non-deduced context

Comment: @PiitrSkotnicki I see, thanks for clarification. Then, one can add a type alias for outer class into `Common`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your following function template:

```
template<typename T, typename... ARGS>
void foo(T::Common tc, ARGS... args);
```

`T` is in a non-deducible context. Therefore, doing:

```
foo(ac, 42, "Hello");
```

won't compile, because `T` can't be deduced from the function call arguments. You would need to explicitly pass `A` as an argument to the `T` template parameter:

```
foo<A>(ac, 42, "Hello");
```

However, note that `T::Common` will actually have to be preceded by the keyword [`typename`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords), since `Common` is a type-dependent name:

```
template<typename T, typename... ARGS>
void foo(typename T::Common tc, ARGS... args);
```

---

#### Extracting the outer class type without giving up implicit type deduction

You could declare an `outer_class_of<>` class template for extracting the outer class. This template would be parameterized by the inner class type:

```
// primary template
template<typename>
struct outer_class_of;
```

Then, specialize this template for both `A::Common` and `B:Common`:

```
// specialization for A::Common
template<>
struct outer_class_of<A::Common> {
    using type = A; // outer class of A::Common
};

// specialization for B::Common
template<>
struct outer_class_of<B::Common> {
    using type = B; // outer class of B::Common
};
```

You can declare then an alias template for achieving C++14-like `_t` type traits:

```
template<typename T>
using outer_class_of_t = typename outer_class_of<T>::type;
```

This way, `outer_class_of_t<A::Common>` corresponds to `A` and `outer_class_of_t<B::Common>` to `B`.

Finally, you need to change your `foo()` function template definition to:

```
template<typename TCommon, typename... ARGS>
void foo(TCommon tc, ARGS... args) { 
   outer_class_of_t<TCommon> t(tc, args...);
}
```

When calling `foo()` with a `A::Common` or a `B::Common` object as function argument, `TCommon` will be deduced to `A::Common` or `B::Common`, respectively. `outer_class_of<>` is then applied on `TCommon` to obtain the type of the outer class.

---

Also, be ware of [C++'s *most vexing parse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) in:

```
A::Common ac();
```

What you want is actually:

```
A::Common ac{};
```

Otherwise, in the call to `foo()`, `TCommon` will be deduced to `A::Common(*)()` (i.e.: a pointer to function) instead of `A::Common`, since the former is declaring a function that takes no parameters and returns an `A::Common` object, whereas the latter is actually declaring an `A::Common` object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is good, but is somewhat complex.

Perhaps a simpler answer (that you are looking for) is that you can do it by explicit template spec calling rather than implicit deduction. This is a question of where you trade off the complexity.

Perhaps it is acceptable for your caller to specify A in the call and write:

foo(ac, 42, "Hello");

You should still put the typename keyword in and a good comment to help the user of your interface

```
template<typename T, typename... ARGS>
void foo(typename T::Common tc, ARGS... args); /// Call with foo<T>(tc, ...)
```